# How to reset the admin password for Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, passwords

I have Bash Ubuntu on Windows 10.  This is enabled by [turning on the Developer mode feature](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) so the normal non-programmer would likely not need this.  I need to reset the password.  I must have typed it wrong (twice, somehow) when I first set it up.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been answered [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-linux-bash-in-windows)

Copying from their answer:

1. In Windows command prompt change the default user to root:

   **lxrun /setdefaultuser root**
2. Now Bash on Ubuntu on Windows logs you in as root without asking password
3. Use passwd command in Bash to change the user password:

   **passwd your_username**
4. Change the default user back to your normal user in Windows command prompt

   **lxrun /setdefaultuser your_username**

Comment: That's it!  Thanks

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>lxrun /setdefaultuser root
Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

Error: 0x80070002

New is: ubuntu1804, but I can't figure out the commands

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit ```"%localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe" config --default-user root``` should do the trick